# PasteButton: Pasting expression name without quotation marks?

Tags: evaluation, button, variable

I am struggling to find a way to use `PasteButton` to paste the name of an expression (in particular a list) without showing the contents of the expression or without wrapping it in quotes.  For example, in this example the values of `myList` `{1,2,3}` is pasted rather than the blackened expression name `myList`.

```
myList={1,2,3}

PasteButton["Paste myList", myList]
```

If instead I use `ToString` then `myList` is pasted with quotation marks around it as `"myList"`:

```
PasteButton["Paste myList", ToString@myList]
```

I simply want the expression name myList without quotes around it so I can choose to evaluate it with <kbd>Shift+Enter</kbd> or not.  There must be something obvious I am missing.  Any suggestions?

Comment: `PasteButton["Paste myList", Defer@myList]`

Comment: @MarcoB  Thanks. Any idea how can I do this with PasteButton if I located myList by using Names["Global`*"]?  For example if Names["Global`*"][[1]] is "myList" how can I use PasteButton to paste it as the blackened text myList and not the values of myList or the string "myList"?

Comment: That seems convoluted. Perhaps you could edit your question to provide more context explaining what you ultimately want to achieve with these manipulations.

Comment: @user13999 Hi, I've seen you have accepted only answer for all your questions. Aren't any of others good enough? Please, take a [**Tour**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: @Kuba Ok, I accepted your answer on the pop-up workspace.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`ToExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToExpression.html) to convert the string to a symbol, with `Defer` as the third argument:

```
symbolname = First@Names["Global`my*"]
(* "myList" *)

PasteButton[ToExpression[symbolname, InputForm, Defer]]
```

Comment: Great, thanks for picking up on my added comment.

Answer (score 3):

Or you can use `RawBoxes`:

```
PasteButton[ RawBoxes @ First @ Names["Global`*"] ]
```

Comment: Cool, never heard of RawBoxes.  Thanks.